# Change background of single top bar item and its dropdown

Tags: css, css-selectors, zurb-foundation

I have a top bar navigation and need a single item and its dropdown to have a different background colour from the rest.  I have managed to change the background colour of the item but cannot change its dropdown.  I have figured out how to change the drop menus for all items and I have tried all different variations to get this to work with the single item but nothing works.

Can anyone help?

Just to clarify, I am trying to select the dropdown on the right hand side with the id of **account** and class of **top-bar-colour**.  Thanks

NB: I am using foundation 5. I originally had that info in the title but someone deleted it, not sure why :/

```
.top-bar-section .top-bar-colour  {background-color:red} //this works
.top-bar-section .dropdown li a {background-color:red} //this doesn't as it changes all dropdowns 
.top-bar-section li a.top-bar-colour .dropdown  li a  { background-color:red} //this doesn't work either

<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar >
                    <ul class="title-area">
                        <!-- Title Area -->
                        <li class="name">&nbsp;</li>
                        <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span></span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <section class="top-bar-section">
                        <!-- main nav section -->
                        <ul class="left">
                            <li><a href="#"><i class="fi-home medium"></a></i></li>
                            <li class="has-dropdown">
                                <a href="#">menu</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="">Dropdown Level 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Dropdown Option</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <ul class="right">
                            <li class="has-dropdown" id="account">
                                <a href="#" class="top-bar-colour"><i class="fi-torso medium"></i></a>
                                <ul class="dropdown"><li><a href="#">Login</a></li></ul> 
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </section>
                </nav>
```

Comment: I am unable to visualize what you want, could you be more specific? Is it **just one** of the `<ul>` with `class=dropdown` you want to change the background color of?

Comment: which dropdowns color do you want to change? the first one? or any specific one?

Comment: I want to change the drop down in the right side which has class="top-bar-colour"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to change the color of the bar and drop down of the first one you can use this css

```
.top-bar-section .left .dropdown li a {background-color:red}
```

Let me know if my assumption is right

Comment: it would actually need to be .right not left and that changes colour of the item but not its dropdown

Comment: I am trying to change the background-color of a drop down menu.  Not sure how your JS fiddle relates to that.

Comment: Yeah if you change the .left to .right then it works on the fiddle but not my project.  I am using Foundation and so must be some other issue.  thanks for your help.

Comment: What if I had another one on the right hand side and wanted to change the 2nd item?

Comment: Ok no problem, but incase you have it hosted somewhere, share the link so that people can check and answer your question :)

Comment: You will use the nth-child property of css. .top-bar-section ul:nth-child(2) .dropdown li a {background-color:red}